# Python QuadTree

Tags: python, pygame, quadtree

I add 2 objects to the QuadTree but when I look through the whole list for the objects I can only find 1 object. Why is this and what can I do to fix it?

```
from pygame import draw

class QuadTree(object):
    def __init__(self, box, current_level, max_level=3):# box (top_left_x, top_left_y, size_x, size_y)
        self.location = (box[0], box[1])
        self.size = (box[2], box[3])
        self.current_level = current_level
        self.max_level = max_level

        self.objects = []
        self.__setupchirldren__()

    def __setupchirldren__(self):
        self.top_right =        None
        self.top_left =         None
        self.bottom_right =     None
        self.bottom_left =      None

    def elements(self):
        if self.current_level == self.max_level:
            for x in self.objects:
                print x, x.rect
        else:
            if self.bottom_left != None:
                self.bottom_left.elements()
            if self.bottom_right != None:
                self.bottom_right.elements()
            if self.top_left != None:
                self.top_left.elements()
            if self.top_right != None:
                self.top_right.elements()

    def add_object(self, new_object, rect):
        if self.current_level == self.max_level:
            #print new_object, rect
            self.objects.append(new_object)
            #print self.objects
        else:
            half_size = (self.size[0]/2, self.size[1]/2)
            if rect.colliderect(self.location, half_size):
                self.top_left =         QuadTree((self.location[0], self.location[1], half_size[0], half_size[1]), self.current_level+1, self.max_level)
                self.top_left.add_object(new_object, rect)
            if rect.colliderect((self.location[0]+half_size[0], self.location[1]), half_size):
                self.top_right =        QuadTree((self.location[0]+half_size[0], self.location[1], half_size[0], half_size[1]), self.current_level+1, self.max_level)
                self.top_right.add_object(new_object, rect)
            if rect.colliderect((self.location[0], self.location[1]+half_size[1]), half_size):
                self.bottom_left =      QuadTree((self.location[0], self.location[1]+half_size[1], half_size[0], half_size[1]), self.current_level+1, self.max_level)
                self.bottom_left.add_object(new_object, rect)
            if rect.colliderect((self.location[0]+half_size[0], self.location[1]+half_size[1]), half_size):
                self.bottom_right =     QuadTree((self.location[0]+half_size[0], self.location[1]+half_size[1], half_size[0], half_size[1] ), self.current_level+1, self.max_level)
                self.bottom_right.add_object(new_object, rect)

    def draw(self, screen):
        #if self.current_level == self.max_level:
        draw.line(screen, (255, 0, 0), self.location, (self.location[0]+self.size[0], self.location[1]))
        draw.line(screen, (255, 0, 0), self.location, (self.location[0], self.location[1]+self.size[1]))
        draw.line(screen, (255, 0, 0), (self.location[0]+self.size[0], self.location[1]+self.size[1]), (self.location[0]+self.size[0], self.location[1]))
        draw.line(screen, (255, 0, 0), (self.location[0]+self.size[0], self.location[1]+self.size[1]), (self.location[0], self.location[1]+self.size[1]))
        if self.current_level != self.max_level:
            if self.bottom_left != None:
                self.bottom_left.draw(screen)
            if self.bottom_right != None:
                self.bottom_right.draw(screen)
            if self.top_left != None:
                self.top_left.draw(screen)
            if self.top_right != None:
                self.top_right.draw(screen)

    def get_elements(self, rect):
        #ret = self.objects
        if self.current_level == self.max_level:
            #print self.objects
            return self.objects
        else:
            half_size = (self.size[0]/2, self.size[1]/2)
            if self.top_left!= None and rect.colliderect((self.location, half_size)):
                return self.top_left.get_elements(rect)
                #for x in self.top_left.get_elements(rect):
                #   ret.append(x)
            if self.top_right!= None and rect.colliderect(((self.location[0]+self.size[0]/2, self.location[1]), half_size)):
                return self.top_right.get_elements(rect)
                #for x in self.top_right.get_elements(rect):
                #   ret.append(x)
            if self.bottom_left!= None and rect.colliderect(((self.location[0], self.location[1]+self.size[1]/2), half_size)):
                return self.bottom_left.get_elements(rect)
                #for x in self.bottom_left.get_elements(rect):
                #   ret.append(x)
            if self.bottom_right!= None and rect.colliderect(((self.location[0]+self.size[0]/2, self.location[1]+self.size[1]/2), half_size)):
                return self.bottom_right.get_elements(rect)
                #for x in self.bottom_right.get_elements(rect):
                #   ret.append(x)
            #print ret
        return []
```

When I insert objects it prints out

> platform.Platforms object at 0x0236F950 platform.Platforms object at
>   0x0236F950 platform.Platforms object at 0x0236F950 platform.Platforms
>   object at 0x0236F950 platform.Platforms object at 0x0236FAB0
>   platform.Platforms object at 0x0236FAB0 platform.Platforms object at
>   0x0236FAB0 platform.Platforms object at 0x0236FAB0

which is good I want two distinct objects in mutable trees
but when I call it it only has the second one in the list

so i made a function

```
def elements(self):
    if self.current_level == self.max_level:
        for x in self.objects:
            print x, x.rect
    else:
        if self.bottom_left != None:
            self.bottom_left.elements()
        if self.bottom_right != None:
            self.bottom_right.elements()
        if self.top_left != None:
            self.top_left.elements()
        if self.top_right != None:
            self.top_right.elements()
```

which prints out

> platform.Platforms object at 0x02320A70 rect(350, 630, 110, 110)
>   platform.Platforms object at 0x02320A70 rect(350, 630, 110, 110)
>   platform.Platforms object at 0x02320A70 rect(350, 630, 110, 110)
>   platform.Platforms object at 0x02320A70 rect(350, 630, 110, 110)

Comment: I read this twice and couldn't find a question either time.

Comment: I updated the post I would love it if you could help my I'm stumped

Comment: Can you post the rest of the quadtree class? Also it's not clear what is wrong with your output, and what it is you expect (partially because the `__repr__`'s are a bit hard to read, and differ between the two examples)

Comment: @dbr I add 3 elements to the quadtree but when ever i look at the tree there is only one element in the tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `add_object` class makes a new lower-level quadtree every time, even if there is already one there.

I was going to suggest this on your earlier quadtree question (pretty sure that was you) but you removed it before I had a chance: you'll probably be better off if the QuadTree class has a method that finds-or-creates the appropriate sub-tree given a location (what you call `rect` in both `add_objects` and `get_elements`).  Note that this assumes that each object lives entirely within one sub-tree, which is true for points but not for arbitrary rectangles.  (The most obvious case is that a very large rectangle—one that covers the entire field—occupies all *four* sub-trees of any given level of quadtree.)

Assuming that the logic in `get_elements` is basically correct, for instance, you might define something like:

```
def find_or_create(self, rect, create = False):
    "find or create the sub-tree that contains the given point"
    if self.current_level == self.max_level:
        return self # we contain it
    half_size = (self.size[0]/2, self.size[1]/2)
    if rect.collide_rect((self.location, half_size)):
        name = 'top_left'
        location = self.location
    else if rect.collide_rect(...):
        name = 'top_right'
        location = ... # top right location
    else ... [as before, each time setting name and location]
    # now, after deciding which sub-quadrant applies...
    quad = getattr(self, name)
    # if the sub-quadrant already exists, recurse
    if quad:
        return quad.find_or_create(rect, create)
    # otherwise, if we are supposed to create it, do that
    if create:
        quad = QuadTree(...) # this is why you also have to compute "location"
        setattr(self, name, quad)
    return quad # return the new quadtree, or None, as appropriate
```

This gives you a way to find the containing quadtree (returning None if it does not exist) or, for adding objects, creating it (returning the existing max-level quadtree, or creating a new max-level quadtree in the appropriate quadrant).

The `getattr` and `setattr` operations let you use the `name` you computed to get and set self.top_left, self.top_right, and so on.

Adding an object is then pretty trivial:

```
    quad = self.find_or_create(rect, True)
    quad.objects.append(new_object)
```

There's a better way to handle the location computation-and-test as well but I leave that as an exercise.  (And, of course, if `rect`s can span multiple sub-trees—if they are not points—you'll need to compute a list of all the appropriate sub-trees, rather than the single appropriate top-left / top-right / bottom-left / bottom-right sub-tree.)

Comment: I feel so dumb. Thanks for pointing that out for me